# Button that deletes image

Tags: javascript, html, razor

Hello I have a foreach loop getting the images from a folder and I want a button at the front of each one that deletes that picture.

I have this:

```
        <td>
            <img class="ola adeus" src="@name" style="width:10%;margin-top:25px;margin-left:25px;" />
            <button onclick="myFunction('22.png')" id="@name"/>
        </td>
```

And

```
    function myFunction(name) {
        var myObject;
        myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        myObject.DeleteFile("~/uploads/" + name);
    }
```

How can I give the function the correct name to delete the image?
Thanks

Comment: where `22.png` placed?

Comment: But that name is a test I want to give the name of the pic that is associated to the button

Comment: I'm mean is it your server or user's storage?

Comment: now while is not online is on my pc, but when it goes online it will be server storage

Comment: so you need to just parse image name to server side and then delete it using that name.